# Read a file after cloning a repository with go-git

Tags: git, go, go-git

I want to be able to do run-time `git` manipulations with `go`.

I recently discovered the [`go-git`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4?tab=doc) package which comes in very handy to this end.

I was also able to perform `pull` operations, more or less as follows:

```golang
import {
  git "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"
}

repo, err := git.Clone(memory.NewStorage(), nil, &git.CloneOptions{
    URL: "https://github.com/pkaramol/myrepo",
})

err := repo.Pull(&git.PullOptions{
    RemoteName: "origin"
})
```

My question is, assuming I am using in-memory checkout of the repo as above), how will I be able to read in (my `go` program) a file from the repository? i.e. assuming the file

```
https://github.com/pkaramol/myrepo/someConfig.yaml
```

Would it be preferable (in case I need **just** this particular file) to perform a git clone (still in mem) of **only** the particular file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From the docs](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4#Clone):

> Clone a repository into the given Storer and worktree Filesystem with the given options, *if worktree is nil a bare repository is created*.

Don't pass a nil filesystem if you want access to the worktree. Use something like [gopkg.in/src-d/go-billy.v4/memfs.Memory](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-billy.v4/memfs):

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"
    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4/storage/memory"
    "gopkg.in/src-d/go-billy.v4/memfs"
)

func main() {
    fs := memfs.New()

    repo, err := git.Clone(memory.NewStorage(), fs, &git.CloneOptions{
        URL: "https://github.com/pkaramol/myrepo",
    })

    file, err := fs.Open("someConfig.yaml")
}
```

You cannot clone a single file (that's not how git works), but you can limit the number of commits that are downloaded using [CloneOptions.Depth](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4#CloneOptions.Depth).

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. fs.Open returns a File struct, which is not an os.File, but a subset of it. So how to get file content from it?

Comment: Answer: 
```
fileContent, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
fmt.Println("File content: %+v\n", string(fileContent))
```